# Is there any universally accepted definition for pain?

Tags: terminology, pain, definitions

There are many terms in the literature of any domain of knowledge that does not have a standard or universally accepted definition. There can be several definitions from several organizations or textbooks. As a CS student, I am aware that there is no single definition for 'Artificial Intelligence.

I believe the same for the word 'pain' in biology. When I read about the opinions and research papers about 'pain in plants', I realized that some experts do believe that plants experience pain and others argue don't as they don't have any central nervous system. As a layman, I feel that pain can be subjective and pain for animals may not be apt to interpret pain experienced by plants.

Is there any universally accepted definition for pain in biology that encompass all living organisms?

Comment: “Pain in plants”? I remember someone in my university Philosophy Department who agonized about this. He left his wife and went to Australia. I’d check whether there is a more appropriate SE site for your question. There are medical yardsticks (I seem to remember childbirth scores high) but universally accepted biological definitions… I think not.

Comment: @David oh. I got the answer from you. If the question is not apt for this site. Please tell me. It is okay for me to remove it if needed.